# List<Model> with a parameter that should come from the dropdownlist when changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view of List type and Model has a selectList which on change should change the actionLink parameter.

I have tried using a form and posting all the contents of the model to the controller but it does not work.

This is part of the view

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.coursenumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.coursename)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.coursescopename)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.avetmiss)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(modelitem => item.InvoiceOptionsId, item.InvoiceOptionsList, "--select--", new {@class = "form-control", id = "ddl" + item.coursenumber})
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Events","Events",new{id= item.coursenumber,priceKey = item.InvoiceOptionsId})
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

The priceKey is calculated from the dropdownlist.

Comment: In order to respond to client side events (selecting an option) you need to use javascript/jquery. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: You should postback (submit) the form when a dropdown item is selected/changed.

Comment: As @StephenMuecke said use javascript to change the actinlink parameters on change of dropdown like $("#ddlCourse1").bind("change", function(){ change params here});'

Comment: I was trying to bind the dropdown value to the ActionLink , the solution given by stephen works and I was complicating my self by thinking abt postbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use javascript/jquery to handle client side events. One option would be to modify the html to (assumes a `for` loop - see notes below)

```
<td>
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].InvoiceOptionsId, Model[i].InvoiceOptionsList, "--select--", new { @class = "form-control" })
</td>
<td>
  <a href="#" class="event" data-id="@Model[i].coursenumber">Events</a>
</td>
```

Then add the following script (requires `jquery{version}.js`)

```
$(function() {
  var url = '@Url.Action("Events")';
  $('.event').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id'); // get the items id
    var priceKey = $(this).closest('tr').find('select').val(); // get the value of the associated dropdown
    location.href = url + '?id=' + id + '&priceKey=' + priceKey; // redirect
  });
});
```

Note: Its not clear if the code you have shown is part of a form that you post back, but if so, you need to use a `for` loop (or custom `EditorTemplate`) to generate the form controls. Using a `foreach` loop generates duplicate `name` attributes (without indexers) which will not bind to your model when you post the form.

Comment: Perfect !
I had tried the editor template with a postback , but this is simple.